# Creating a Notification from a Service

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Im using GCM service to send a message from a node js server, in the device is recived in a Service, and finally display it in a notification. All works and the device receive the notification,however, in the moment i want to create the notification it does not show it. I'm very lost about that maybe i'm missing something on the notification's creation. I'm guiding my self with the gcm example provided by google, Although, im not able to show the notification.

Here is the code of the service:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("TableMeNot");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    sendNotification(message);

}
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("You have a new notification!!!")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "NOTIFICATION CREATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" );
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How does your server-side code look? How are you sending the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_msg_box_copy)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))

                        .setContentText("New message");

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Did not work, maybe is necessary to specify something on the manifest about the service?

Comment: I mean, so the service can create the notification?

Comment: is your service working ? Have you mentioned your service in manifest.xml?